# Can't put a certain expression in IF clause in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

The following works fine:

```
@echo off
youtube-dl --output D:\path\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9bjJEjK2dQ
```

I can add an `IF` clause (and I get the expected 'hi'):

```
@echo off
IF 1==1 (
    echo hi
)
youtube-dl --output D:\path\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9bjJEjK2dQ
```

But when I put `youtube-dl` in the `IF` clause, it doesn't work. I get `s.%(ext)s was unexpected at this time.`, without `hi`.

```
@echo off
IF 1==1 (
    echo hi
    youtube-dl --output D:\path\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9bjJEjK2dQ
)
```

Same thing if I put the output path in a variable:

```
@echo off
set OUTPUT=D:\path\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s
IF 1==1 (
    echo hi
    youtube-dl --output %OUTPUT% -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9bjJEjK2dQ
)
```

The variable itself is not the problem, as the following works fine:

```
@echo off
set OUTPUT=D:\path\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s
IF 1==1 (
    echo hi
)
youtube-dl --output %OUTPUT% -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9bjJEjK2dQ
```

How do I put the thing in the `IF` clause?

Comment: Could you finish the title please - I'm not sure what to change it to, otherwise I'd do it myself. It's an interesting problem, and a better title will get more visibility.

Comment: @KenY-N Whoops, done!

Comment: Seems most likely the `(` / `)` in the command line. You'll likely need to quote and/or escape them.

Comment: If you turned off `echo off` to read CMD's messages you see it's your brackets. Escape them with `^`.

Comment: @Noodles @Iridium It worked. Removing `@echo off`, though, did not show a difference. The paths appeared exactly identical, and printing the whole thing into cmd manually worked. Anyway, feel free to add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Iridium for the solution. Brackets inside the `IF()` need to be escaped, so `(` becomes `^(` and `)` becomes `^)`.

```
@echo off
IF 1==1 (
    echo hi
    youtube-dl --output D:\path\%%^(title^)s.%%^(ext^)s -f bestaudio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9bjJEjK2dQ
)
```